# How do I setup AdMob to only display app and game advertisements

Tags: admob

How do I setup AdMob to only display app and game ads in my game?

I only want app and game advertisements in my game. I think someone playing my game would rather tap or view advertisements of other games and apps because the user is obviously interested in games and apps. Also, my game is targeted towards children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off advertising categories like so:

1. Go to [**AdMob.com**](https://apps.admob.com/#home)
2. Click Monetize
3. Click on the App in question
4. Click General Categories
5. Turn off the categories of ads you **DO NOT** want displayed in your
   application.
6. Click Sensitive Categories
7. Repeat step 5

Comment: thanks, I see you can only block 50 categories in admob... so you wont be able to block all except mobile games

Comment: @Renier sorry, I was not aware there was a cap on the number of ad categories you could block. If you were able to get it close to just the game category ads being left you could deny the other ad categories ads by using the **Ad Review Center** tool https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3480906?ref_topic=3480859. This is kind of a brute force way of accomplishing what you have in mind but may help slightly.